# Ways to physically secure laptop that has no kensington lock

Tags: laptop, physical-security

My company is planning to buy several laptops for demonstration purposes in a convention stand. Previously, we always bought laptops that have kensington slots for the typical cable locks.

Now, the laptop we are liking most is an ultrabook with no kensington slot, and we are looking for a mechanism that does not need the slot.

Please do not provide software options, what we are trying to do is to stop the theft of the hardware.

Thanks

Comment: Can you specify exactly what the laptops you're looking at are?  It may be relevant.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It would seem that Kensington has identified the lack of a lock slot on ultrabooks and the like. They have a solution:

> Security Slot Adapter Kit for Ultrabook™

[image: k lock]

That they sell here: [Security Slot Adapter Kit for Ultrabook™](https://www.kensington.com/us/us/4483/k64995ww/security-slot-adapter-kit-for-ultrabook) and at the time of this post, it seems resonably priced at $12.99 US.

Comment: I've used these before, the glue they use is pretty hardcore. Highly recomend.

Comment: Then how shall we remove it when reselling the laptop. It's great for security, but well not really a fantastic solution. I hope industrials will come with a solution !

Comment: @Brice - I would think this may be a value added option once attached and set up for resale. But the question was not about reselling the unit, it was how to secure an ultrabook with no lock in a public area.

Comment: @CarlB Granted, I wanted to highlight the fact that this K-Slot adapter is almost permanent and that could be an issue. And I personally don't like this "hump". That being said I agree with you it's one of the best solution out there for securing the hardware. :)

Answer (score 8):

Kensington does have a device that actually locks arms in place around the screens...depending on the exact laptop in question it may interfere with the visuals, though.  They claim it will work on any standard 13"-17" laptop.

[Laptop Locking Station](http://www.kensington.com/kensington/us/us/p/1479/K64625WW/laptop-locking-station.aspx)

Comment: The Op noted the focus of ultra books. At least as I read it. Just wanted to point that out. ;)

Comment: @CarlB - There are 13" Ultrabooks! :)

Comment: If the adjustable bar doesn't run full length you could probably mod it for an 11.6" model with a hacksaw.

Comment: @DanNeely - I would presume it's designed to be hard to hacksaw, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 5):

I have found a very good solution for laptops or ultrabooks that do not have a Kensington type of locking slot anymore:

J-Plug Lock from Multplx.

https://security.multplx.com/products/jplug_lock/

I have ordered the J-Plug directly with the manufacturer in the UK as there are basically no stores/distributors in the EU yet.

I assume that the J-Plug was initially made for lage scale use to prevent demo devices from theft (e.g.: exhibitions, large sales stores, etc...).

The people at Multplx really did a great customer service job for my tiny, tiny one item order. Called me twice from the UK to Germany to handle my inquiry and the order itself.

The J-Plug (with loop) and the Tetrakey Security Tool (needed to actually lock/unlock the J-Plug from the 3.5 audio jack) arrived in less than 24 hours (UK to Germany).

J-Plug Lock: 23 GBP
Tetrakey Security Tool: 12 GBP
Shipping UK to Germany with DHL: 29 GBP

I am really very impressed by the speed this single item order was handled by Multplx.

I have of course immediately tried it and I must say: it is really what I was looking for.

If you are looking for a physcial lock for your YOGA 900+ ultrabook or any other ultrabook that does not have a Kensington lock option and DOES have a 3.5 audio jack: J-Plug Lock imho is the perfect lock.

I would suggest a small closeable (zipper) bag/pouch or the like to keep the lock in it while travelling, so you do not loose the needle bracket and/or the back cover. If the Multplx Tool (screwdriver) fits in there as well, even better :)

Here is an image of my J-Plug Lock that arrived yesterday attached to my YOGA 910s:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about a metal bar against the laptop right above the keyboard, between the keyboard and the screen, so the metal bar will hold the laptop against the surface it is on. Wouldn't this work?

**EDIT**
Shinrai's post about a Kensington locking station is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. How about something much simpler: An movement based alarm with a small ball in contact with a level surface so that you may slide it to and fro and lift it, say 3 inches to feel the weight, all connected to a USB (individual or hub).

If you yank the device itself, it rings.
If you grab the laptop, again it rings loudly. 
No disconnect possible without a coded entry to "safely remove the device". 
The alarm itself would be quite small but would pack a high decibel screech.

I just retired as a mechanical engineer! 
Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more practical solution as compared to locks using the USB port or even the glue-on type. VGA port type lock looks reliable but Ultrabook only comes with a mini VGA port.

http://www3.pny.com/Portable-Laptop-Locking-System-font-colordc0431-Special-Offerfont-P3227C541.aspx

Comment: Could you update the link? It's not working anymore.

Answer (score -1):

I found and purchased a great solution from Multplx called the Anchor laptop security lock adapter, it locks into my 3.5mm headphone port in seconds and allows me to attach my existing t-bar laptop lock cable to it!, its made from aluminium and looks great
Got it from their online store
https://store.multplx.com/collections/laptops/products/laptop-security-anchor